# OpenGL ES 2.0 texture appears black

Tags: c, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on an application using OpenGL ES 2.0 for an embedded device.

This is my fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);
}
```

I set up the textures properly. For some reason, calling `glTexImage2D` is not producing the result I'm looking for. The texture is entirely black, rather than being filled with the data I provide it.

This is how I create the texture:

```
   GLuint textureId;

   // 2x2 Image, 3 bytes per pixel (R, G, B)
   GLubyte pixels[6 * 3] =
   {  
      255,   0,   0, // Red
        0, 255,   0, // Green
        0,   0, 255, // Blue
      255, 255,   0,  // Yellow
        0, 255, 255,
        255, 0, 255
   };

   // Use tightly packed data
   glPixelStorei ( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );

   // Generate a texture object
   glGenTextures ( 1, &textureId );

   // Bind the texture object
   glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId );

   // Load the texture
   glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 3, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );


   // Set the filtering mode
   glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
   glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
```

Afterward, I bind the texture like so:

```
samplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation ( userData->programObject, "s_texture" );
glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId );

// Set the sampler texture unit to 0
glUniform1i ( samplerLoc, 0 );
```

I confirmed that the vertex and texture coordinates are bound and passed to the shaders when debugging. So, it has to be an issue with `s_texture` or the `glTexImage2D` function itself.

Comment: Did you check for errors using `GetError`?  You may also be calling `TexImage` and `TexParameter` in the wrong order (`TexParameter` typically comes before `TexImage`), though I'm not sure if that affects anything.  That said, it's very unlikely to be an issue with `TexImage`, and is almost definitely a mistake on your part.

Comment: Yea I did. No error was recorded. I know it cant be vertex shader, coz when i debugged i saw that vertex coordinates and texture coordinates are passed correctly. Its pretty much a straight forward example from textbook. I dont know what I missed. :(

Comment: May also be because your texture either isn't square or its dimensions are not a power of two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the clamp modes to `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for both U and V dimensions, otherwise the texture is incomplete and will sample as black.

Comment: OMG!!! It worked thanks!!

But I cant seem to explain why I need to set up clamping because all my texture coordinates were within the range.

But thanks anyway!!

Comment: Non power of two textures need clamp_to_edge to work(among others), that's why.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069441/non-power-of-two-textures-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but if you are storing only 2 x 2 pixels with 3 bytes per color (= 4 x 3 bytes = 12 bytes) as a texture; then where does the 6 in "GLubyte pixels[6 * 3]" come from?

6*3 equals 18 and != power of 2

> // Load the texture glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, **3, 2**, 0,
> GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );

From the spec:
glTexImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint internalFormat, **GLsizei width, GLsizei height**, GLint border, GLenum format, GLenum type, const GLvoid * data);

Bolded vars are best a ^2...

So, try this:

> // Load the texture glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, **2, 2**, 0,
> GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );

Delete the last 2 rows from your pixels array, then change all values to "255"; if you get a white texture, that means it's working.

Another example:

> GLubyte pixels[4 * 3] =    {
>
> 255, 0, 0, //Red //Green //Blue // pixel 0
>
> 255, 0, 0, //Red //Green //Blue // pixel 1
>
> 255, 0, 0, //Red //Green //Blue // pixel 2
>
> 255, 0, 0 //Red //Green //Blue // pixel 3
>
> };

And everything shows up red.

If that doesnt do it, perhaps my code will help :

```
void CMesh::renderMesh(GLuint program, glm::mat4 *mvp){

glUseProgram(program);

int mvpLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "matViewProjection");
int texLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "baseMap");
glUniformMatrix4fv( mvpLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(*mvp));

int vertexAttribLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vertex");
int uvAttribLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "texturecoordinate");

// Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIndex);
glUniform1i(texLocation, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
   vertexAttribLocation,            
   3,                               // size
   GL_FLOAT,                        // type
   GL_FALSE,                        // normalized?
   0,                               // stride
   (void*)0                         // array buffer offset
);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
   uvAttribLocation,                  
   2,                  // size
   GL_FLOAT,           // type
   GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
   0,                  // stride
   (void*)0            // array buffer offset
);

// Draw the triangles !
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size() );

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
};
```

Comment: I'm assuming his 2x2 is a typo.

Comment: Nick, I'm sorry...you're right. I missed that one.
But even then, 3 x 2 textures?